# Methods to move PKI certificates from browser to document in Address Book (Lotus Domino)

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Just looking to see what other methods people have come up with to move the user's x.509 certificate (from browser) to place in Address Book (to be used for authentication).  I have developed one using LDAP but wanted to know if anyone else has come up with any other ways of doing this.

V/R,

Kev